# django user_passes_test decorator

Tags: python, django

How do I implement the `@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)` decorator for class based views? I have used this before for function based views, and I have a workaround but it feels unnaturally.

Shouldn't this be covered by the dispatch method?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-the-class

Comment: See below, but also note that u.is_superuser is a boolean field on the User model, NOT a method. So u.is_superuser() is incorrect - should be just u.is_superuser.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You use `@method_decorator` on the `dispatch` method of the class:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

class MyView(View):
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I actually just copied your code from above without looking at it really. `is_superuser` is an attribute, so it doesn't need the parenthesis afterwards.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with `TemplateView` — says `'MyView' object has no attribute 'user'`.

Comment: You don't need to use it on the dispatch method, saving you overwriting it: `@method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser), name='dispatch')
class MyView(...):`

Answer (score 26):

Building on @Chris Pratt's answer, you'll probably want to do this in multiple view classes  so it makes sense to turn it into a mixin.

```
class SuperuserRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SuperuserRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Usage

```
class MyView(SuperuserRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

To prevent unexpected [MRO](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) bugs, ensure the mixin is the first inherited class.

You can implement a `LoginRequiredMixin`, or any other common tests you use in your app, in the same way.

**Edit:** [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#permission-mixins-for-class-based-views) adds AccessMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, and UserPassesTestMixin

Answer (score 1):

I have used the @view_decorator from this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2505/ to wrap my normal function decorators.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces) and its [UserPassesTestMixin](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#userpassestestmixin).